# Alternative way to check if a string contains multiple strings in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, substring

I currently have the following code

```
fun main() {
    // Build.Fingerprint sample strings
    val debug_fingerprint: String? = "Company/device/device:11/3526.4353/0064504902000:userdebug/com-d,dev-keys"
    val dev_fingerprint: String? = "Company/device/device:11/526.4353/0064504902000:user/com-d,dev-keys"
    val user_fingerprint: String? = "Company/device/device:11/526.4353/0064504902000:user/com-p,release-keys"
    

    //Testing
    val osVarient: String = user_fingerprint?.let {
            when {
                check(listOf("userdebug", "dev-keys"), it) -> "Userdebug"
                check(listOf("user", "dev-keys"), it) -> "Userdevsigned"
                check(listOf("user", "release-keys"), it) -> "User"
                else -> "Unknown variant"
            }
        } ?: run {
            "Unknown variant null"
        }  
    print(osVarient)
}
fun check(args: List<String>,fingerprint: String): Boolean {
    for(arg in args) {
        if(!fingerprint.contains(arg)){
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

The above code works but I'm wondering if there is more elegant way of writing the code.

Are there any alternatives in Kotlin to compare multiple substrings to a string?

Comment: Do you only want to return True/False based on whether one or more of the substrings is present in the string?

Comment: I want to return true only if all substrings are present in the string. Else, return false

Answer (score 2):

You may use a dictionary for `OS variants`.
`Iterable<T>.all` is a builtin kotlin stdlib function to check a predicate on all elements.

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val userFingerprint: String? = "Company/device/device:11/526.4353/0064504902000:user/com-p,release-keys"

  val variantMap = mapOf(
      "Userdebug" to listOf("userdebug", "dev-keys"),
      "Userdevsigned" to listOf("user", "dev-keys"),
      "User" to listOf("user", "release-keys")
  )

  val osVariant = userFingerprint?.let { fingerprint ->
    variantMap.entries
        .firstOrNull { check(it.value, fingerprint) }
        ?.key
  } ?: "Unknown variant null"

  println(osVariant)
}

fun check(fingerprintTypes: List<String>, fingerprint: String): Boolean {
  return fingerprintTypes.all { it in fingerprint } 
  // return fingerprintTypes.all { fingerprint.contains(it) }
}
```

Comment: Or, slightly more concisely: `fingerprintTypes.all{ it in fingerprint }`.

Comment: Kotlin has always a way to make code more concise. Thanks @gidds

Comment: My pleasure :-) (I dunno why, but that use of `in` seems to be a common blind-spot — I rarely see anyone else using it, even though I find it easier to read than calling `contains()`…)

Comment: I use also `in` but in this question it did not pop up. @gidds